# How to float a DIV in the center of screen when position:fixed?

Tags: html, css

I am referring to the red ribbon banner at [This Website](http://classictutorials.com/)

Now when the position not set this code works, to make it center aligned.

```
margin: 0 auto 30px;
```

But when i scroll down and make the div `position:fixed` with a JS the same code wont work! What should i do to make it center aligned even though the screen resolution/browser keeps on changing?

Comment: btw i misunderstood you, i thought that classictutorials is a site you want to copy from. Didn't get it that it's YOUR site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
{
 position:fixed;
 left:50%;
 margin-left:470px;

}
```

**Here the link of screenshot after debugging using chrome developers tool:**
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/19982181/Screen-Shot-2012-06-22-at-12.35.jpg

**In your window.scroll function change this.**

```
$('#socio').css({
"position":"fixed",
"margin-left":"-470px",
"top": "27px",
"left": "50%"
});
```

Comment: Nice one ! But this only works if the element has a static width.

Comment: @Panique #socio div has a fixed with of 940px. I am just saying to change its style on scroll.

Comment: @SVS even with % this thing doesn't works with different browser size.

Comment: The link does not work anymore!

Answer (score 0):

Because the element on the page gets a

```
margin-left: XXXpx;
```

when you scroll down. This is done via JS, i guess it simply measures the width between the left browser border and the element itself via jQuery's .offset() => http://api.jquery.com/offset/

EDIT: Personally I would also prefer SVS's answer, but this only works when you know the width of the element.

Comment: SVS answer wont work as told in the comment below it.. This is also not helping.. Their should be some easy way.. all i need is to center a div with position being fixed!

Comment: @KD ??? SVS's answer is perfect. You have to set this on element:hover, not on the base element.

Comment: @KD My code is EXACTLY how http://classictutorials.com/ did it. Its what you see when you inspect the page via chrome's web dev tool or firebug.

Comment: Probably i am not able to understand. Let me try again. classictutorials.com has a JS code which puts the modified CSS when we scroll down a certain point. The cSS do the following.>> Makes the #Socio element position:fixed and some leftmargine.  I understand till here. All am asking is how to make this #Socio div float in the middle. The leftmargine is not generated dynamically. Its fixed value. So with different resolution this code breaks. Should i go ahead and recalculate the browser size and based on it do or is their an easier way to do it?

Comment: @KD exactly ! jQuery does not simply "center" the div, is sets the amount to the left browser border "manually" when you scroll. It's because a fixed element cannot float.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
```